# Remove Event Listeners that need to Receive Multiple Arguments JS

Tags: javascript

I built a tab that a user can close using touch events and when the tab closes I want to be able to remove event listeners. This is a little bit tricky because in my actual code there is a modal and there is a part in that dynamically inserted content that the touch events are attached to.

So if i have the below code

```js
const tab = document.querySelector('.tab')

function handleMove(e, tab) {
  e.preventDefault()
  tab.style....
}

// I add the event listener like this
// but then I can't remove it
tab.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
  handleMove(e, tab)
})
```

Below is more realistic with what I am dealing with.

```js
const swipeTab = document.querySelector('.swipeable-tab')

let y1, timeStart, timeEnd

function closeStart(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0]
  y1 = touchLocation.clientY
  console.log({ y1 })
  timeStart = e.timeStamp
}


function closeMove(e, swipeTab) {
  e.preventDefault()
  swipeTab.style.transform = ''
  let touchLocation = e.touches[0]
  let yLocation = touchLocation.clientY

  if (yLocation > swipeTab.clientHeight + y1) {
    yLocation = swipeTab.clientHeight + y1
  }

  swipeTab.style.transition = ''
  let marker = yLocation - y1
  console.log({ marker })

  if (marker < 0) {
    marker = 0
  }
  
  swipeTab.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${marker}px, 0)`
}



function closeEnd(e, swipeTab) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let touchLocation = e.changedTouches[0]; 
  let y2 = touchLocation.clientY; 
  let yDiff = y2 - y1; 
  console.log({ yDiff })
  timeEnd = e.timeStamp; 
  timeDiff = timeEnd - timeStart; 
  console.log({ y2 })
  console.log({ timeDiff })

  if (yDiff > swipeTab.clientHeight/3 || timeDiff < 50) {
    closeTab(swipeTab)
  } else {
    openTab(swipeTab)
  }

}


function openTab(swipeTab) {
  swipeTab.style.transition = `all 0.2s ease-in-out`
  swipeTab.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0%, 0)`
  addCloseEventListeners(swipeTab)
}

/**
 * I am trying to come up with something similar to this
*/

function closeTab(swipeTab) {
  swipeTab.style.transition = `all 0.2s ease-in-out`
  swipeTab.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 100%, 0)`
  removeCloseEventListeners(tab)
}

function removeCloseEventListeners(swipeTab) {
  swipeTab.removeEventListener('touchstart', closeStart); 
  swipeTab.removeEventListener('touchmove', closeMove); 
  swipeTab.removeEventListener('touchend', closeEnd); 
}


/**
 * when open(swipeTab) is called
 * then the event listeners are added for closing the tab
*/
function addCloseEventListeners(swipeTab) {

  swipeTab.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
    closeStart(e)
  }) 

  swipeTab.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
    closeMove(e, swipeTab)
  })

  swipeTab.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
    closeEnd(e, swipeTab)
  })
 }


/**
 * this is where it starts
*/
open(swipeTab)
```

Comment: You're passing anonymous functions when adding, so there's no way to remove them without storing references to those functions.

Comment: I know, that was my question, how could I implement this so that I could make this work. In other words how could I utilize a named function? Do I need to use closures or some kind of wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make more variables.

```js
function removeCloseEventListeners(swipeTab) {
  swipeTab.removeEventListener("touchstart", swipeTouchStart);
  swipeTab.removeEventListener("touchmove", swipeTouchMove);
  swipeTab.removeEventListener("touchend", swipeTouchEnd);
}

const swipeTouchStart = (e) => closeStart(e);
const swipeTouchMove = (e) => closeMove(e, swipeTab);
const swipeTouchEnd = (e) => closeEnd(e, swipeTab);

function addCloseEventListeners(swipeTab) {
  swipeTab.addEventListener("touchstart", swipeTouchStart);
  swipeTab.addEventListener("touchmove", swipeTouchMove);
  swipeTab.addEventListener("touchend", swipeTouchEnd);
}
```

---

Also, you don't need to make your functions take `swipeTab` as a parameter:

```js
function addCloseEventListeners() {
```

since `swipeTab` is already a global variable in the script.

Comment: This creates closures over `swipeTab`

Comment: Probably OK here since `swipeTab` is a constant that is assigned to an HTML element.

Comment: Awesome, easy to read and simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: Then no reason to accept it as a parameter.

Comment: I know, I did that for the sake of this example, but as I noted above, the `swipeTab` is not global, it's a dynamically created element in a modal.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a helper function that adds a listener and returns a callback holding a `removeEventListener()` with the same signature that it was added with. You can then store these callbacks to be used in the `removeCloseEventListeners()` function, here using a global array and setting it's length to 0 after use.

This will redeclare the callbacks for each event with the passed `swipeTab` as argument and as the element the events will be attached to. It also avoids the repetition in your current code allowing you to define the events once in `addCloseEventListeners()` without having to also add/edit them in the close function.

```
function addEventListenerWithAnonymousCallback(element, event, cb, options = {}) {
  element.addEventListener(event, cb, options);
  
  return () => element.removeEventListener(event, cb, options);
}

const closeListeners = [];
function removeCloseEventListeners() {
  for (const removeListener of closeListeners) {
    removeListener();
  }
  closeListeners.length = 0;
}

function addCloseEventListeners(swipeTab) {
  const listeners = [
    ["touchstart", (e) => closeStart(e)]
    ["touchmove", (e) => closeMove(e, swipeTab)],
    ["touchend", (e) => closeEnd(e, swipeTab)],
  ];

  for (const [event, cb] of listeners) {
    const removeListener = addEventListenerWithAnonymousCallback(swipeTab, event, cb);
    closeListeners.push(removeListener);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool implementation, I like that.